# how to find values between a range in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a db named **student** and I want to select the values between 30 and 60 from a column named u1. This is the query I used,but it shows some error

```
db.student.find($and:[{u1:{$gt:30}},{u1:{$lt:60}}])
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

try this:

```
db.student.find({ u1 : { $gt :  30, $lt : 60}});
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also try this:

```
db.students.find({$and:[{u1:{$gt:30}},{u1:{$lt:60}}]})
```

The above statement will display the value of the field `u1` which are in between 30 and 60

Comment: For me, this syntax also works when interfacing MongoDB via mongo-express advanced query, while the accepted answer does not.