# Find All Records Between a Range of Two Numbers in a MongoDB Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, range

Is there a way in MongoDB to get records between a range of numbers?

In my example, I am finding the records that match `common: 1`, and am using a fake `range()` function to get only the records between that range. In theory, you could just put any numbers in the range function and it would output the records in that range.

This is not what I am asking: [$gte, $gt, $lte, $lt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365283/how-to-find-values-between-a-range-in-mongodb)

**Note:** I am not querying based on values. I am querying based on the records natural position in the filesystem relative to all other records.

**Users Collection:**

```js
db.users = [{
    _id: 123,
    name: "Bill",
    common: 4
  },
  {
    _id: 456,
    name: "Jeff",
    common: 2
  },
  {
    _id: 789,
    name: "Steve",
    common: 4
  },
  {
    _id: 321,
    name: "Elon",
    common: 3
  },
  {
    _id: 654,
    name: "Larry",
    common: 1
  },
]
```

**Unworking Example:** (range() isn't a real function, just used to give an idea)

```js
users.find({common: 4}).range(0, 2).then((users) => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

**Expected Result:** (because the common fields match and the records are between the range 0 and 2)

```js
db.users = [{
    _id: 123,
    name: "Bill",
    common: 4
  },
  {
    _id: 789,
    name: "Steve",
    common: 4
  },
]
```

Comment: You can use a query filter with `$gte` and `$lt` operators.

Comment: @prasad_ I thought those were just to test if a records value is gte or lt?

Comment: gte 0 and lt 5, gives a range of 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. Its a range query. You can pass the variable values for gte and lt.

Comment: @prasad_ You are misunderstanding. I am not querying based on values. I am querying based on the records natural position in the filesystem relative to all other records.

Comment: You can put all records in an array field, and slice the array as per your range criteria - it can be an aggregation query.

Comment: @eol oops, I changed 1 to 4 because people where somehow getting the idea that I am searching based on the value of "common" being between 0 and 2.

Comment: I did not suggest a JS method.

Comment: @prasad_ It seems like the $slice only works on array values within the document and not on the documents themselves? I could be wrong.

Comment: use  [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)?

Comment: @1sina1 Yeah I just figured that out just before you posted lmao

Comment: oh i just saw your answer now : )

Comment: I don't get you. Query `users.find({common: 4})` returns exactly what you expect. Note, documents in MongoDB (like almost all other databases) do not have any order.  "based on the records natural position in the filesystem" is not determined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't give the exact expected result, but the whole idea was to select records between two numbers (eg. a range). The way you do this is with the $skip and $limit methods.

```js
users.aggregate([{$skip: 1}, {$limit: 3}, {$match: {common: 4}} ]).then((users) => {
  console.log(users)
})
```

Comment: first skip and limit then match, check https://mongoplayground.net/p/U6h9vHZy-0t

Comment: @1sina1 Is your example more efficient/faster because it doesn't search past the limit but because mine searches past the limit and then limits, it must search unnecessarily?

Comment: im not sure what exactly do you want, your example match the `common: 4` and then skip and limit based on the result of that, for example in this array `[4, 3, 4, 2, 4]` it will match all the `4` and return all of them `[4, 4, 4]`  and then it will do the skip and limit on  the new result between 0 and 2 , but in my example it first skip and limit between 0 and 2 so result of that will be `[4, 3, 4]` and then the match stage will retrun `[4, 4]`